# Redux async actioncreator not recognizing then

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-thunk

I need to use `.then()` on a redux action, what is wrong in the following action?

```
export const userLogin = (username, password) => {
  return dispatch => {
    axios.post(`${TT_API_BASE}/Access/Login`, { username: username, password: password, applicationId: 2 }, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + auth,
      }
    })
      .then(response => {
        dispatch({
          type: LOGIN,
          payload: response.data
        })
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        dispatch({
          type: LOGIN_FAILED
        })
      })
  }
}
```

It is then called in a component like this

```
  handlePress() {
    this.props.userLogin(this.state.username, this.state.password)
      .then(() => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('SelectInstance')
      })
  }
```

Which displays the errormessage that then is not defined. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by doing this:

```
export const userLogin = (username, password) => {
  return async dispatch => {
    const onSuccess = data => {
      dispatch({
        type: LOGIN,
        payload: data
      })
    }
    const onError = err => {
      dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_FAILED
      })
    }
    try {
      const req = await axios.post(`${TT_API_BASE}/Access/Login`, { username: username, password: password, applicationId: 2 }, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
          'Authorization': 'Basic ' + auth,
        }
      })
      return onSuccess(req.data)
    }
    catch (err) {
      return onError(err)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `dispatch(someThunkActionCreator())`, the return value of `dispatch` is whatever your thunk function returns.  So, you can only do `dispatch().then()` if the thunk function returns a promise.

Your thunk is making an AJAX call, but not actually returning a promise, so it actually returns `undefined`.  Putting a `return` statement in front of `axios.post()` will return that promise and fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however that did not solve it.